# ng-if creates non-smooth jumps/transitions when digest cycle updates its value

Tags: angularjs

I've found with certain elements that their hiding/transitions aren't smooth on update of the element's `ng-if` or some other altering property.

E.g, I have a button that, when clicked, will make an API call, verify some data, then update the `ng-if` that will show/hide it. See screencast:

http://screencast.com/t/sPLxZVetbqYD

```
button class="buttons purple" ng-if="!question_container.checked_answer 
  && (selections.length || question_container.answered)" 
  ng-click="checkAnswer()">Check Answer</button>
```

the ng-click's `checkAnswer()` makes an API call then sets portions of the `ng-if` conditional true.

```
$scope.checkAnswer = function() {
    verifyAnswer().then(function (res) {
        $scope.question_container.checked_answer = res; //will be true or false
```

I'm assuming this is obviously from the delay in the API call, so I added a second `checked_answer` and set it to true prior to the API call to hide the button immediately:

```
$scope.checkAnswer = function() {
    $scope.question_container.checked_answer = true;
    verifyAnswer().then(function (res) {
```

The delay/flickering still occurs. How can I smooth the display of elements on the page?

Comment: Have you considered a loading spinner? When a user clicks an answer, disable the button & show a spinner until the promise is resolved. You could just have a `pending` state that would show/hide the spinner on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a transition to the ngif.

Per the Angular documentation:

```
<label>Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label><br/>
Show when checked:
<span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
  This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
</span>

.animate-if {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Working Example found here:  [Ngif With Transition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

On top of that, if the issue is the delay with the api request, then adding some type of [spinner](http://loading.io/) or using ngclass to grey out the area that needs updating usually works best.

Comment: I've added transitions, but you can still see the images and buttons jump/swap around: http://www.screencast.com/t/oZYRPEmmid

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can smooth this out?

Comment: I am unable to view the video without installing quicktime.  Can you find a different way to show to the issue?